# Tensorflow in Python 2.7 Environment in Anaconda 5.1 on Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

Both Anaconda2 and Anaconda3 (version 5.1), on Windows, are having trouble installing Tensorflow in the Python2.7 environment. In Anaconda2, installing Tensorflow shows multiple conflicts and in Anaconda3, installing Tensorflow updates Python2.7 environment to Python3.6.

This seems to be a problem specifically for Windows release, the Linux version seems to be working fine.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow does not support Python 2.7 on Windows. Due to restrictions on what compiler may be used to build [Python 2.7 extensions on Windows](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers), and that compiler not being able to build TensorFlow, it is only possible to support Python 3.5 and later.

A theoretical workaround would be to build a custom version of the Python 2.7 interpreter using Visual C++ 14.0 (Visual Studio 2015), and then build TensorFlow for Python 2.7 using the same compiler. There are instructions for build Python (and some unofficial downloads) [here](http://www.p-nand-q.com/python/building-python-27-with-visual_studio.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This workaround seems to be much more work than I had hoped for :-) Just asking for Linux box at work might be easier or at least I can install Linux on a VM.